# Magnitude relation of fractions for four real numbers with a condition

Tags: fractions

I would like to know if the following proposition holds or not.

For all $a, b, c, d$ such that $a, b, c, d$ are positive real numbers,
IF $a < b$ and $a - c > b - d \geq 0$ THEN $\frac{c}{a} < \frac{d}{b}$ .

Could you kindly advise?

It is really appreciated if a proof or a counterexample is provided.

Best regards,

Comment: you have the problems with a or b being 0, and do you really want to allow negative numbers as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's false. $a=1$ ; $b=2$ ; $c = 3$ ; $d=5$ is a counterexample.

We have $a<b$, $a-c=-2$ and $b-d = -3$ so $a-c>b-d$.

$\frac{c}{a}=3$ and $\frac{d}{b}=2.5$ so we don't have $\frac{c}{a} <\frac{d}{b}$

**EDIT** : With your new constraints, I believe this is true.

$a-c>b-d$ so $\frac{a}{c}-1> \frac{b-d}{c}$.

$d>c$ (because $a<b$ and $a-c>b-d$) so $\frac{1}{c} > \frac{1}{d}$ and since now we have $b-d\geq 0$,  $\frac{b-d}{c} \geq \frac{b-d}{d} = \frac{b}{d}-1$.

So $\frac{a}{c}-1> \frac{b}{d}-1$ and $\frac{a}{c}> \frac{b}{d}$. So $\frac{c}{a}<\frac{d}{b}$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I forgot a condition.
Amended the question.

Comment: I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I think the proof is correct.

Comment: You're welcome, it's my pleasure. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept my answer if it has helped you ! :)